# Error with an RPC request and don't understand the error

Tags: godot

I'm trying to make a dedicated server and a client with godot, I can connect to the server through internet, but when I make an RPC, I get this error :

> ERROR: Node not found: gamestate
>      At: scene/main/node.cpp:1382
>
> ERROR: _process_get_node: Failed to get path from RPC: gamestate
>      At: core/io/multiplayer_api.cpp:248
>
> ERROR: Invalid packet received. Requested node was not found.
>      At: core/io/multiplayer_api.cpp:194

Server :

```
func _client_connected(id):
    print('Client ' + str(id) + ' is connected')
    var newClient = load("res://remote_client.tscn").instance()
    newClient.set_name(str(id))
    get_tree().get_root().add_child(newClient)
remote func _register_player_to_server(id, info):
    players_server[id] = info
```

Client :

```
func connect_to_server(player_nickname, ip):
    self_data.name = player_nickname
    get_tree().connect('connected_to_server', self, '_connected_to_server')
    var peer = NetworkedMultiplayerENet.new()
    if ip == null or ip == '':
        peer.create_client(DEFAULT_IP, DEFAULT_PORT)
    else:
        peer.create_client(ip, DEFAULT_PORT)
    get_tree().set_network_peer(peer)

func _connected_to_server():
    players[get_tree().get_network_unique_id()] = self_data
    print("here")
    rpc_id(1, '_register_player_to_server', get_tree().get_network_unique_id(), self_data)
    print("wtf")
```

The `_conneccted_to_server()` func should call the `_register_player_to_server()` func in the server which then stores the value info of players.

Note that client is in a singleton named gamestate and that the error shows up in the server's console.

Answer (score -1):

My nodes weren't on the path (thus the error).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm getting the same error.